# Why can only int be calculated in return when using ndk build?

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to make a project using jni into aar. However, simple int calculation seems to be possible with return in the cpp part, but I don't know why an error occurs when I try to use the if statement.

Ultimately, I want to perform http communication in cpp and parse html and return the result.

This is to make refactoring difficult when making aar.

I am sorry that my English is not good.

### this my code

```
package kr.go.murldc2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class murldc2 {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("helloNdk");
    }
    public native String print_ndk(String text);
    public native int add_ndk(int a, int b);

    public void showToast(Context context, String s){
        String printss = print_ndk(s);
        int sum = add_ndk(1,2);
        System.out.println(sum);
        Toast.makeText(context,printss,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

---

android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := helloNdk
FILES := hello_ndk.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILES)
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

---

//

```
// Created by flsor on 2022-10-06.
//
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<kr_go_murldc2_murldc2.h>

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_kr_go_murldc2_murldc2_print_1ndk
        (JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jstring text) {
    jstring str = (jstring) "stri";
    if(text != str){
        return (jstring)"notsame";
    }
    return text;
}
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_kr_go_murldc2_murldc2_add_1ndk
        (JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jint a,jint b) {
    return a+b+3;
}
```

this is my error:

```
E/kr.go.kootest2: JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed stale Local 0xc09443b5 (index 201933883 in a table of size 6) A/kr.go.kootest2: java_vm_ext.cc:577] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of deleted local reference 0xc09443b5 java_vm_ext.cc:577] from java.lang.String kr.go.murldc2.murldc2.print_ndk(java.lang.String) A/kr.go.kootest2: runtime.cc:655] Runtime aborting... runtime.cc:655] Dumping all threads without mutator lock held runtime.cc:655] All threads: runtime.cc:655] DALVIK THREADS (21):
```

Comment: You need to use `GetStringUTFChars` to get the characters from a string. `(jstring) "stri"` won't work nor will `text != str` nor `return (jstring)"notsame"`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have an additional question, can you answer it?
If so, should I use jstring after converting it to GetStringUTFChars and return it to jstring? Or can I return GetStringUTFChars right away? I also saw an article two or three years ago telling me to use std::. However, when I tried to use this method, I only got an error. Is that a problematic way?

Comment: `GetStringUTFChars` does not "convert" anything. It copies the contents of the string to a new memory buffer for you to examine. You *must* call `ReleaseStringUTFChars` after you are done with it or you will leak memory. A common practice is to initialize a `std::string` instance with the new memory buffer (which copies it) so you can safely call the Release immediately afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

A `jstring` is a (local or global) reference to a `java.lang.String` object. You cannot simply cast a `const char *` to `jstring` and expect it to work.

The tools for working with jstrings are as follows:

- `env->NewStringUTF`: this will construct a Java String from a local `const char *` using the modified UTF-8 encoding
- `env->GetStringUTFChars`: this will (potentially) take a copy of the String contents and give you a `char *` to the copy. You need to call `env->ReleaseStringUTFChars` afterwards
- You can call methods of `java.lang.String` using the standard `GetMethodID`/`Call<Type>Method` functions.

Comment: I didn't fully understand, but I think I found a way to solve it. I'll look for more based on what you told me. Thank you.

Comment: You should start by reading at least the first few sections of the [JNI specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/specs/jni/). There is also a [JNI cookbook](https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook) with common code fragments; you should study that as well.

Comment: I'm not an English speaker, I'm weak with documents like this. So, it was a rule of thumb, but now I need to get closer to these documents. I'll study hard. Thank you.